# Euler's constant $e$ correctness of definition

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, definition, constants

Recently I started considering derivative (calculating it by definition) of an exponential function $a^x$. It requires couple of additional steps, one of them is to define constant $e$ as the only real number that satisfies:

$$ 1 = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} $$

And here I am stuck. Why such definition is correct? First we must prove that fot every real number $r$ exists such $a$ that

$$ r = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} $$

And I do not know how to proceed with it. Any suggestions? Concept of proof?

Comment: This is an awkward definition, for exactly the reason you give. In fact this limit is equal to $\log a$ but showing this is easiest by defining the natural exponential and logarithm some other way first. Personally I think it's cleaner to define $e^x$ to be the unique function $f(x)$ satisfying $f'(x) = f(x)$ and $f(0) = 1$ (existence and uniqueness is guaranteed by the Picard-Lindelof theorem). Then $e$ is the value of this function at $1$, but the real point is to define $e^x$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for remark, I am coming back to such maths and considerations after 4 years... And I really like the way of calculating exponential function derviative by definition this way. That's why I really would like to find that missing piece, which is stated in question.

Answer (score 2):

The online textbook [CLP-1 Differential Calculus](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7ECLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/index.html) (by Feldman/Rechnitzer/Yeager) develops the derivative of exponential functions in exactly this way; they include a proof that there is a unique such number in [Section 2.7](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7ECLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/sec_exp_func.html) (especially Section 2.7.2).

Comment: Thanks for poitning to the useful source!